# How to use this lua obfuscator

Tags: lua

I was wondering how to use this lua obfuscator https://github.com/efrederickson/XFuscator

I have tried using it doing lua XFuscator.lua `C:\script.lua` but that has not been working out for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadstring` is a global function from Lua 5.1 and earlier. In Lua 5.2 that function was [renamed](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2) `load`, though 5.2 [could be compiled](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lbaselib.c.html#base_funcs) with `loadstring` as an alternative name. So I guess you must be using Lua 5.3, while XFuscator was designed under Lua 5.1 or 5.2. Replacing `loadstring` with `load` should fix this error at least.